# How do i store the output from cout into a variable

Tags: c++, output, cout

I am making a C++ program to estimate your height based on your parents. I want to make it so I can output both the height in Feet and Inches. I don't know how to store the output from the cout in

```
if (boygirl == "boy") {
    cout <<"Your estimated height is " << (mom *13/12 + dad) / 2  << " inches";
} and   else if (boygirl == "girl") {
    cout <<"Your estimated height is " << (dad+12/13 + mom) / 2   <<" inches";
```

into a variable so I can take the data from the variable and use it instead of asking for the results for inches in the previous step.

You might need to run the code to see what I mean.
If you don't understand what I mean, feel free to comment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Convert(int inch) {
    int feet, inches;
    inches = inch % 12;
    feet = inch / 12;
    cout << "\n\t\tThe height in feet is " << feet << "\'" << inches << "\" " << endl;
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    do {
        float mom;
        float dad;
        string doyouwish;
        string boygirl;

        cout << " \n\nWELCOME TO THE C++ HEIGHT PREDICTION PROGRAM";
        cout << "\n\n INPUT GENDER TO BEGIN boy/girl: ";
        cin >> boygirl;

        cout << "How tall is your mother in inches: ";
        cin >> mom;
        cout << "How tall is your father in inches: ";
        cin >> dad;

        if (boygirl == "boy") {
            cout << "Your estimated height is " << (mom * 13 / 12 + dad) / 2 << " inches";
        } else if (boygirl == "girl") {
            cout << "Your estimated height is " << (dad + 12 / 13 + mom) / 2 << " inches";
        }

        int htInches;
        // Ask height from user
        cout << "\n\ntEnter height in Inches from the previous results: ";
        cin >> htInches;

        Convert(htInches);
        cout << "\n\n\n";

        ++i;
    } while (i < 10);
}
```

Comment: You should store the result in the variable first, then use it (the variable) in your cout.

Comment: Instead of using  int htInches;
        cout << "\n\nEnter height in Inches from the previous results: ";
        cin >> htInches; I would like to use the data from the variable and apply it to Covert(output); cout<< "\n\n\n";

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
int htInches = 0;
if (boygirl == "boy") {
  htInches = (mom * 13 / 12 + dad) / 2;
} else if (boygirl == "girl") {
  htInches = (dad + 12 / 13 + mom) / 2;
}
cout << "Your estimated height is " << htInches << " inches";
```

Compute the result, store it in a variable, and *then* print it.

Comment: I want to keep the inches but then in my code i made it so i could also print the result in feet. I don't know how to get to git rid of the section that asks for the result they got from inches. I want to edit my code so i can automatically store the previous result and plug it into the Convert function without asking for user input.

Comment: In my example, you have the result they got with the inches, assigned to the variable named `htInches`. In what way do you feel this fails to satisfy your needs?

Comment: I need the results also in feet. Not just inches

Comment: So call `Convert(htInches)`, as you are doing already. Just drop the `cin >> htInches;` part (and the preceding prompt). I fail to grasp the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: I am trying to drop the user input so i can get to look like this